# Error: Relation ["table name"] does not exist

Tags: postgresql, table

I am trying to create tables based on relational schema, but I get "Relation does not exist" errors for some tables and could not find a way to get out of this. I will display my schema, code, and actual errors below. I really feel this might have a simple solution, but I just got stuck into it..
[image: Relational schema]

```
CREATE TABLE Driver 
( 
Id           CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
FirstName    VARCHAR(15)   NOT NULL,
LastName     VARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL,     
Phone        CHAR(12)      CHECK (char_length(Phone) > 8),

PRIMARY KEY  (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Driving 
(
Id           CHAR(11)         REFERENCES Driver ON DELETE CASCADE,
BusId        INT              REFERENCES Bus    ON DELETE CASCADE,

PRIMARY KEY  (Id, BusId)
);

CREATE TABLE Bus
(
BusId    INT           NOT NULL,
Make     VARCHAR(20)   DEFAULT ('Volvo'),
Model    VARCHAR(20),
Year     SMALLINT      NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT ManufacturingYear 
                                         CHECK ((Year > 1970) AND 
                                                (Year < date_part('year', current_date) + 1)),
 Space   SMALLINT      CHECK (Space > 0),
 Route   SERIAL,

 PRIMARY KEY (BusId),
 FOREIGN KEY (Route) REFERENCES Route ON DELETE SET NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE Route
(
RouteId          SERIAL         NOT NULL,
StartingPoint    SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
EndingPoint      SMALLINT       NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(RouteId),
FOREIGN KEY (StartingPoint) REFERENCES Stop,
FOREIGN KEY (EndingPoint) REFERENCES Stop
);

CREATE TABLE RouteStops
(
Route       SERIAL,
Stop        SMALLINT,

PRIMARY KEY(Route, Stop),
FOREIGN KEY (Route)  REFERENCES Route  ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (Stop)   REFERENCES Stop   ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Stop 
(
StopId    SMALLINT      NOT NULL,
Name      VARCHAR(30)   DEFAULT ('Station'),

PRIMARY KEY(StopId)
);
```

Errors:

```
ERROR:  relation "bus" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "route" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "stop" does not exist
ERROR:  relation "route" does not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to create relations (constraint) before create parent objects, for example:

order #2:

```
CREATE TABLE Driving 
(
Id           CHAR(11)         REFERENCES Driver ON DELETE CASCADE,
BusId        INT              REFERENCES Bus    ON DELETE CASCADE,

PRIMARY KEY  (Id, BusId)
);
```

but table Bus at this moment not created.

2 possible solutions:

1. Create tables in order - from parent to child (not always possible)
2. Create all tables without constraints and add all of them after